# Animate (walk) gltf clone objects from one position to another

Tags: animation, three.js, gltf

I am working on a project where I imported a gltf humanoid that has animations. I am creating clones of the imported model to display in the scene, rather than creating a new one every time.

I have walk and idle animations for the loaded model. How can I animate the cloned in such a way that it appears like they are walking from one location to another another. For example, if the cloned model is at position (10, 20, 0) at time = 1s and it will be at position (13, 20, 0) at time = 2s, I would like it to appear that the model is walking between the positions. I read the new Animation System documentation and did a lot of searching but it didn't help.

Thanks for your help.

P.S: I cannot share the code from the project due to restrictions.

Comment: How did yo clone the model? I have tried using THREE.SkeletonUtils.clone(), but doesnt appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the direction by subtracting both vectors and then normalizing it.

```
let direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(destination.position, object.position).normalize();
```

Then in your render function update object position on each frame in that direction. Speed variable value is up to you (default 1).

```
object.position.x += direction.x * speed;
object.position.y += direction.y * speed;
object.position.z += direction.z * speed;
```

You would need a boolean value like `isMoving` or distance between objects to know when to start and stop.

```
object.position.distanceTo( destination.position );
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo

As for the animation I think you just want to call animation.play() on start and animation.stop() when you reach the destination.

Comment: I am having trouble with animation.play(). It isn't doing anything on the clones. However, if I create a new model for every user, I can see animation playing. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I cant do much without a code sample. Do you create a new mixer for every clone?

Comment: From https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14494, note that cloning a skinned mesh currently requires extra work.

Comment: I am doing something similar to the folllowing code:
var model,clip,clonedModel;
function loadGLTFModel(){
var loader = new THREE.GKTFLoader();
loader.load( 'model.glb', function ( loadedModel ) {
model = loadedModel.scene;
clip = model.animations[ 0 ];
});
}
function createClone(model){
clonedModel = model.clone();
clonedModel.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( clonedModel );
mixers.push( clonedModel.mixer );
var action = clonedModel.mixer.clipAction( clip );
action.play();
scene.add( clonedModel );
}

Comment: Thanks @DonMcCurdy. I will try that approach.

Comment: "clonedModel(model.clone())" - you cant call clone function on a scene (model = gltf.scene)

Comment: .clone of a SkinnedMesh doesn't also clone it's skeleton. You'll have to fix up your clone to refer to a new skeleton with the proper bones copied into it.